# Java program works in Eclipse but not as a Jar file

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, awtrobot

I'm very new to programming and to learn something I made a simple auto clicker. My problem is that when I export it to jar using Eclipse or the command prompt the simulation of clicks doesn't work. It does load the GUI but when I press the button for it to start it doesn't start clicking at all. If you have any idea of how I might fix this, I would be very thankful for any help I can get.

Edit: Tried some things which was mentioned in the duplicate but it still doesn't work :/

Comment: @HugoSousa When I run it through the console I don't get any error. It loads the GUI with the buttons but when I click the start button nothing happens and I don't get any error in the command prompt either.

Answer (score 0):

If the GUI is showing, your jar is running.  My guess is that you're depending on some library, and the JVM can't find it.

Run the jar from the command line:

```
java -jar <filename> <args>
```

And see if you get any error messages, that will give you a clue as to what is going wrong.

Comment: No Idon't get any errors :( it opens the GUI and if I press the start button nothing happens and I don't get any error messages then either